# Retrieve from database via mgo using interface

Tags: mongodb, interface, go, mgo

I have following (untested) function:

```
func Execute(task MyInterface) {
    db := session.DB(task.Database()).C(task.Collection())
    var tasks []MyInterface
    db.Find(nil).All(&tasks)
    for _, t := range tasks { t.Do() }
}
```

I want to give my function a struct that implements interface `MyInterface`. It should then retrieve some values from mongodb and call a method on the retrieved structs.

Problem is `error: reflect.Set: value of type bson.M is not assignable to type mypkg.MyInterface` - is there some way to make this work? I tried to instantiate `tasks` using the type of the original struct, but couldn't get it working.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks :)

Comment: When you say

"I tried to instantiate tasks using the type of the original struct, but couldn't get it working."

what was the error and how did you do it? Was tasks of type []MyInterface of []MyStructType?

Comment: @JimPaek: Sry, that was poorly written: I just tried to figure out how to instantiate the structs original type. And found no way. (What I wanted was `MyStructType`).

Answer (score 1):

`mgo` can't create `MyInterface` objects since MyInterface is just an interface. Try doing :

```
myObject := &MyInterface{}  //fails
```

I think it's basically what `mgo` is trying to do for each record it tries to unmarshal.

To achieve what you want, make `tasks` of type `[]map[string]interface{}` or `[]bson.M` (the latter is an alias for the former) and then:

```
for _, o := range tasks {
    t := &MyTypeThatImplementsMyInterface{ 
        Field1 : o["my_field"],
        //etc.  
    } 
    t.Do()
}
```

Either that or make `tasks` a slice of objects of a type (`var tasks []MyStructType`) that implements `MyInterface` and that its fields match the keys and values types of your bson objects in your database. That might not work if your stored data is of more than one type implementing `MyInterface`, hence the slice of maps option above.

Also, be cautious with `Find(nil).All(&tasks)`. If you have millions of records in that collection, depending on the records size, you may fall short of memory.

Comment: I see. Yeah, there are a lot of unknown types that implement that interface (I mean, that's what interfaces are for...). Does that mean, there is solution to my problem? Or can I somehow dynamically create `MyTypeThatImplementsMyInterface` structs?

Comment: Consider using an iterator http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Iter. You could retrieve each record in a bson.M object, then test the presence of fields and then create a concrete object from them.